# Better estimate on binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ when $k=(1-o(1))n$?

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, inequality

For binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$, I know one inequality saying that
$$\binom{n}{k}\le (en/k)^k.$$

While for $k=(1-\epsilon)n$ if $\epsilon$ is an $o(1)$-term, where we assume $n$ tends to infinity, the above inequality gives an exponential bound. I am wondering is there a better estimate on $\binom{n}{k}$ in this case?

Comment: Have you considered $\binom nk = \binom n{n-k}$?

Comment: Maybe [this paper](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/shagnik/notes/binomials.pdf) can help.

Comment: Isn't that the Poisson PDF?

Comment: You might look up Joel Spencer's short book *Asymptopia*, which has very readable discussions of bounds on binomial coefficients on various ranges (among other things)

Comment: Wikipedia also lists the bounds
$$\frac{n^k}{k^k}\leq \binom{n}{k}\leq \frac{n^k}{k!}$$
And the asymptotic expansion for $k\ll n$
$$\binom{n}{k}\asymp \left(\frac{\mathrm e n}{k}\right)^k~\sqrt{2\pi k}~\exp\left(\frac{-k^2}{2n}(1+o(1))\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\binom{a}{b}=\binom{a}{a-b}$ as long as $b<a$. This means
$$\binom{n}{(1-\epsilon)n}=\binom{n}{\epsilon n}$$
So we may as well call $\epsilon n\to\epsilon$. (We are only diddling around with orders of magnitude of $\epsilon$.)

Remember
$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$

So using the Gamma function,
$$\binom{n}{x}=\frac{\Gamma(1+n)}{\Gamma(1+n-x)\Gamma(1+x)}$$
We can already make some progress using the recursive properties of Gamma and Euler's reflection formula. Note
$$\Gamma(1+n-x)=\Gamma(1-x)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k-x)$$
Combining this with Euler's reflection formula, we get
$$\binom{n}{x}=n!\operatorname{sinc}(\pi x)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(n-k-x)}$$
Writing the factorial as a product,
$$\binom{n}{x}=\operatorname{sinc}(\pi x)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-k)}{(n-k-x)} \\ =\operatorname{sinc}(\pi x)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{n-k}} \\ =\operatorname{sinc}(\pi x)\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{x}{n-k}\right)\right)^{-1}$$

So, we need to figure out how to estimate
$$P_n(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{x}{n-k}\right)$$

> **Lemma:** Let $$P_n(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{x}{n-k}\right)$$ be a degree $n$ polynomial with coefficients $a_0,a_1,\dots ,a_n$. Then clearly $a_1=-H_n$, where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number.

### **Proof.**

We proceed with induction. Clearly the $n=1$ case is true. Now:
$$P_{n+1}(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{n}\left(1-\frac{x}{n+1-k}\right)  \\ =\left(1-\frac{x}{n+1}\right)\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{x}{n-(k-1)}\right)\\  =\left(1-\frac{x}{n+1}\right)P_n(x) \\ =\left(1-\frac{x}{n+1}\right)\big(1-H_n x+a_2x^2+\dots\big) \\ =1-H_n x-\frac{x}{n+1}+\text{higher order terms} \\ =1-H_{n+1}x+\text{higher order terms}$$
$\blacksquare$

Finally, taking $H_n\asymp \gamma+\log(n)$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, we have
$$\boxed{\binom{n}{x}\approx \operatorname{sinc}(\pi x)\frac{1}{1-(\gamma+\log n)x}} \\ \text{as}~n\to\infty~\text{and}~x\to 0$$
You can of course take $\operatorname{sinc}(z)\approx 1$ for small $z$ if you'd like.

This approximation is a bit crude, for sure. If you want more accuracy, unfortunately you will have to crunch more coefficients of $P_n(x)$. This is by no means easy. But I have a sneaking suspicion it has to do with polygamma functions.

---

### EDIT 1: On the coefficients of $P_n(x)$.

We have the exact expression
$$\binom{n}{x}=\operatorname{sinc}(\pi x)\frac{1}{P_n(x)}$$
Where $P_n(x)$ are polynomials given by
$$P_n(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{x}{n-k}\right)$$
They can be alternatively defined by the recurrence
$$P_{n}(x)=\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)P_{n-1}(x) \\ P_1(x)=1-x$$

We let $0\leq k\leq n$ and consider the $k$th coefficient of $P_n(x)$. Call it $a_{n,k}$. We have
$$P_n(x)=\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_{n-1,k}x^k\right) \\ =\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{n-1,k}x^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}a_{n-1,k}x^{k+1}$$
Playing around with the summations,
$$P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{n-1,k}x^k-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}a_{n-1,k-1}x^{k} \\ =a_{n-1,0}-\frac{1}{n}a_{n-1,n-1}x^n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(a_{n-1,k}-\frac{1}{n}a_{n-1,k-1}\right)x^k \\ =a_{n,0}+a_{n,n}x^n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{n,k}x^k$$
From which we get the equations
$$a_{n,0}=1 \\ a_{n,n}=(-1)^n n! \\ \boxed{a_{n,k}=a_{n-1,k}-\frac{1}{n}a_{n-1,k-1}}$$
Good  luck!

---

### **EDIT 2: An exact expression for the coefficients of $P_n(x)$.**

Remember that
$$P_n(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{x}{n-k}\right)$$
Which can be reshuffled a little bit:
$$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{n!}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k-x) \\ =\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x-n+k) \\ =\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x-k) \\=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{x-n}{x}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x-k)$$
But $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x-k)$ is a falling factorial, and can be expressed using [signed Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number#Expansions_of_falling_and_rising_factorials):
$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x-k)=\sum_{k=0}^ns(n,k)x^k$$
So
$$P_n(x)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left(1-\frac{n}{x}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n}s(n,k)x^k$$
However, it is known that $s(n,0)=0~\forall n\in\Bbb N$, so we can rewrite this as
$$P_n(x)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n s(n,k)x^k-\frac{n}{x}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}s(n,k+1)x^{k+1}\right) \\ =\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n s(n,k)x^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}n~s(n,k+1)x^k\right) \\ =\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left(-n~s(n,1)+n~s(n,n+1)x^n+\sum_{k=1}^n s(n,k)x^k-\sum_{k=1}^{n}n~s(n,k+1)x^k\right)$$
Combining the sums and using $s(n,n+1)=0$ and $s(n,1)=(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!$ we get
$$P_n(x)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left(-n(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!+\sum_{k=1}^n \left(s(n,k)-n~s(n,k+1)\right)x^k\right)$$

So
$$P_n(x)=1+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\big(s(n,k)-n~s(n,k+1)\big)x^k$$

But - this is amazing! The signed Stirling numbers of the first kind obey the [recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Recurrence_relation)
$$s(n+1,k)=-n~s(n,k)+s(n,k-1)$$
Which can be rearranged to give
$$s(n+1,k+1)=s(n,k)-n~s(n,k+1)$$
Which can be inserted into our expression for $P_n(x)$ to give
$$P_n(x)=1+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}s(n+1,k+1) x^k$$
Or alternatively we can introduce the **un**signed Stirling numbers of the first kind,
$$\begin{bmatrix}n\\k\end{bmatrix}=(-1)^{n-k}s(n,k)$$

Verified for e.g $n=7$:

[image: mathematica verification]
Hence
$$\boxed{P_n(x)=1+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n!}\begin{bmatrix}n+1\\k+1\end{bmatrix}(-1)^k x^k}$$

---

### **EDIT 3**

Computation of Stirling numbers is generally speaking very hard, but there are a few [known formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Expansions_for_fixed_k),
$$\begin{bmatrix}n+1\\2\end{bmatrix}=n!H_n \\ \begin{bmatrix}n+1\\3\end{bmatrix}=\frac{n!}{2}\left((H_n)^2-H^{(2)}_n\right) \\ \begin{bmatrix}n+1\\4\end{bmatrix}=\frac{n!}{3!}\left((H_n)^3-3H_nH^{(2)}_n+2H^{(3)}_n\right) \\ \text{and} \\ \begin{bmatrix}n\\n-1\end{bmatrix}=\binom{n}{2} \\ \begin{bmatrix}n\\n-2\end{bmatrix}=\frac{3n-1}{4}\binom{n}{3} \\ \begin{bmatrix}n\\n-3\end{bmatrix}=\binom{n}{2}\binom{n}{4}$$

Where $H^{(m)}_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^m}$ is a generalized harmonic number.

But things get very complicated very fast.

Comment: Just realized - unfortunately this formula does not work for integer $x$, because $\operatorname{sinc}(\pi x)=0$. More work needs to be done to rectify this.